# Should I choose Boost Asio or Aysnc Socket threads in Android?

Tags: sockets, android-asynctask, boost-asio, android-networking

I am in process of developing an network based UI app for Android which would perform following kind of functionalities

1. Needs to communicate with TCP servers running on n/w based embedded devices (>100 at a time).
2. Polling these devices at regular intervals for fetching updated information
3. Sending and receiving information from those devices
4. All above information would be controlled and managed by application's UI

Considering above situations, the app would probably have to spawn multiple thread's for multiple connections and managing them.So my query is

1. Is it good approach to develop the network module using Boost.Asio libraries ? Or it is okay to open upto 100 of socket threads for connectivity?
2. If Boost.Asio is used, then network module would be developed seperately using NDK, to access JNI would come into place, which in turn could lead to slow response?

Alternatively, can there be other better options? Looking forward for your inputs!

Many thanks in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I suggest taking a look at [New I/O](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/New_I/O), which is supported on Android. Using it you can handle multiple connections in a single thread, the API is similar in principle to Posix `select()` call.

If you decide to go for your second option (networking code implemented in C/C++) I don't think you should be worried about JNI performance. Significant part of Android APIs is just a thin JNI wrapper on top of C/C++ anyway.

Comment: Thanks a lot for suggesting New I/O, one of reason of analysing boost asio is because later the code can be used for other platforms as well, especially iOS.

Comment: If so, then JNI is probably the way to go. It really isn't that heavy, overhead is usually negligible. Also it depends on how frequently you cross Java/C boundaries, it might be better to put more functionality into C/C++ if you need high performance. But well, we'd need to know more about this particular project.